# Pass chossen image stream or camera image stream from one page to another ... with out showing the first page any more during nevication

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have 2 pages in windows phone application:

Page A : lets the user to choose an image or take a new one using camera.
         saves the image stream on an Application setting.
         (Now need to move to Page B, with out showing the Page A any more)

Page B : shows the chosen image.

But the problem is, when the image is chosen or taken, Page A shows up for a very short time like a flash screen. Then nevigets to the Page B. To solve this I have worked with:

```
NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry()
//to remove Page A from the stack.
```

and:

```
NavigationService.Source = new Uri("/Windows/ImageEditorWindow.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
//to set my Page B as the current source.
```

But its not working well. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're calling the task on the page A. Of course, when the task is finished, your page gets back to where it was, which was page A, and only then navigates.

One possible solution would be to move the following action:

*lets the user to choose an image or take a new one using camera. saves the image stream on an Application setting. (Now need to move to Page B, with out showing the Page A any more)*

from page A to page B. That way the navigation would happen before the task for choosing a picture is launched.